# Azure Resource Group template for Cloud Service and Notification Hub

Tags: azure, azure-deployment

I'm trying to create Azure Resource Group template for an application consisting of: Cloud Service (with single WebRole), Notification Hub, Azure Storage and Azure SQL.

I started in VS2013 by creating AzureResourceGroup project and using the JSON Outline i can add storage and SQL resources. But Cloud Service and Notification Hub is missing in Add Resource dialog. What is the schema for them? What is the best way to add them to the template?

**Edit:** I found schema for NotificatonHubs [here](http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-04-01/Microsoft.NotificationHubs.json#/definitions/notificationHubs) and was able to add template for it. Still don't know how to define the Cloud Service.

Comment: Can you use a VM rather than a web role? Azure Resource Manager doesn't have good support for Web Roles/Cloud Services, but the VM/IaaS support is very good. You should be able to do everything with a VM as well, i.e. set the hostname, automatics updates, etc.

Comment: No, I don't want to change PaaS for IaaS just because of missing bits in relatively new feature.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Services are in a "private preview" on ARM so we won't have snippets in VS until it goes public.  I *think* that you have to be whitelisted as part of the preview to deploy at the moment...  (i.e. the deployment will fail if you're not whitelisted)

Comment: Is there an update on this? When does it look like we can get this included in the ARM template? Also, is there a timeline / roadmap / plan on what template functionality is being worked on and in what stage you're at? I'm looking for dacpac deployment as well as Notification Hub and extended Web App deployment (deploy multiple virtual directories to one web site)

Comment: Any idea when Cloud Services on ARM goes public?